# homestead not working - yaml file missing?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, yaml, homestead

I have installed virtualBox and Vagrant and Laravel.
When running 'homestead up' I get the error that a vm is not specified.
After some research I discovered that doing an 'bash init.sh' in my Homestead dir. does not create a yaml file in the .homestead directory. Instead I have a Homestead directory in my user directory which does have a yaml file, but the .homestead is empty.

Could this be the cause for the error?
vagrant box lists three machines including laravel/homestead
the Vagrantfile shows the correct box as well.
vagrant status gives me 'default' as the box which is running.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `vagrant up`?

Comment: yes i did. that works. Shows it is starting machinge laravel/homestead. but only homestead up does not work.

Comment: So I guess you were following this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#daily-usage Could you add your script, OS and the path to your homestead installation?